# c# parse date with incorrect timezone format

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I have method to validate and parse date:

```
public static bool TryParse(string dateTimeString)
{
    var format = "ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
    DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset;
    var result = DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(dateTimeString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out dateTimeOffset);
    return result;
}
```

But from client I have Date in this format: `"Fri, 22 Jan 2021 15:31:07 +0300"`.
So as I understood timezone is incorrect

`+0300` - incorrect.

`+03:00` - correct.

And my method doesn't parse date (returns `false`).

So in the result I have this format `"Fri, 22 Jan 2021 15:31:07 +0300"` and I can't change it.
How can I properly parse Date such as `"Fri, 22 Jan 2021 15:31:07 +0300"`?

Comment: `Fri, 22 Jan 2021 15:31:07 +0300` is a string, not a Date. Where does it come from? User input? A control? JavaScript formatting code? The best solution is to avoid converting dates to strings completely. In .NET/ASP.NET all date pickers return a `DateTime` or `DateTiimeOffset`. In JavaScript, you have a `Date` type which can be serialized to an ISO8601 string with [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: "And my method fails here." it works fine on my machine... so `result` is `false` when you try it?

Comment: @MongZhu I mean it should parse but it isn't parsing Date.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's Date from SMTP server, so I can't change this format, I need to parse it.

Comment: @A.Gladkiy check if all characters in your input are actually what you think they are. There are a lot of unicodes caracters that look like others, or aren't printed. For instance, a non-breaking space or a zero-width space.

Answer (score 2):

The `:` is optional when it came as an offset "z" format specifier, check the source here:

```
// ':' is optional.
if (str.Match(":")) {
   // Found ':'
    if (!ParseDigits(ref str, 2, out minuteOffset)) {
      return (false);
    }} else {
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,3010

Comment: Why then I can't parse Date? Anything wrong in my code?

Comment: no I don't think so. if you try it here https://dotnetfiddle.net/EH6ty4 you will see your code works perfectly fine. is the input string you provided in the question the one failing?

Comment: yes, you are right, it works, strange thing.